# « Comment vous vous appelez ? » Est-ce une question correcte ?

Tags: questions

En général on peut poser des questions de trois manières différentes, par exemple :

1. **Monsieur, vous vous appelez comment ?** (avec intonation)
2. **Monsieur, comment est-ce que vous vous appelez ?** (avec *est-ce que*)
3. **Monsieur, comment vous appelez-vous ?** (avec inversion)

Pourtant, récemment j’ai entendu la même question posée de cette manière :

4. **Monsieur, comment vous vous appelez ?**

Selon les règles que je connais, le mot interrogatif se met à la fin d’une question avec intonation. Si on met le mot interrogatif au début, il faut utiliser *est-ce que* ou inversion. La question 4 est en fait une combinaison des formulations des questions 1 et 2.

Est-ce du français correct dans la question 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**La meilleure forme est la 3**, en inversant verbe et sujet:

> Monsieur, comment vous appelez-vous ?

**La forme 2 est correcte également**, mais un peu plus lourde, et plus facile à construire: adverbe interrogatif + est-ce que + forme affirmative:

> Monsieur, comment est-ce que vous vous appelez ?

Elle est souvent utilisée en langage courant.

**Les formes 1 et 4 ne sont pas correctes** en tant que constructions, mais fréquemment utilisées, surtout dans le langage courant. 
Elles sont construites comme: forme affirmative + adverbe interrogatif (début ou fin de phrase) + ? et sont donc faciles à construire.

**L'important est de mettre l'accent sur l'adverbe.**

Comment: I just added a question related to this one [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17919/comment-tu-tappelles-versus-vous-vous-appelez-comment)

Answer (score 1):

**Comment vous vous appelez?** est plus familier que les autres examples. On peut l'utiliser dans le langage courant. Par contre, il faut monter l'intonation vers la fin de la phrase pour que ce soit une question.

Comment: Une toute petite remarque: "ou entre amis". Je ne crois pas qu'entre amis on se vouvoie ou surtout qu'on demande le nom de l'autre...

Comment: @BernardMasse En effet !