# Word order in questions

Tags: ordre-des-mots, questions, inversion

> Depuis quand ce magasin est-il ouvert ?

Is it correct if you rephrase this question to:

> Depuis quand est ce magasin ouvert ?

or

> Depuis quand il est ouvert ?

Comment: [This answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/17928/358) seems to answer your question.

Comment: @oldergod: I am not a native speaker, but I learned to use the additional pronoun as in sentence #1 rather than moving the noun phrase as in sentence #2. The following site seems to say that both strategies are possible but using an extra pronoun is more common after longer question words: http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/questions.shtml

Answer (score 5):

For a general discussion, you might want to look at the answers of the possible duplicate questions mentioned in the question comments. As for your particular word orders:

1. Depuis quand ce magasin est-il ouvert ?

   - Formal (I would never say it and tend to avoid writing it)
2. Depuis quand est ce magasin ouvert ?

   - Not French at all, the inverted position for the clitic *il* is on the auxiliary, the inverted position for full NP subjects is after the past participle. The corresponding form would be :
     => Depuis quand est ouvert ce magasin ? (also quite formal)
     NB. This word order does not seem to work with attributes
     => *Depuis quand est majeur ton fils ?
     => Depuis quand ton fils est-il majeur ?
     => Depuis quand est-il majeur, ton fils ?
3. Depuis quand il est ouvert ?

   - Informal, with many other possibilities
     Depuis quand ce magasin est ouvert ?
     Depuis quand est-ce que ce magasin est ouvert ?
     Depuis quand est-ce qu'il est ouvert, ce magasin ?
     ...

Answer (score -4):

Les 3 sont utilisables.

La première est celle à préférer.

La seconde n'est pas très correcte (mais souvent utilisée) et plus lourde. Il vaudrait mieux dire:

> Depuis quand est ouvert ce magasin ?

La troisième n'est pas très correcte à l'écrit, mais très souvent employée à l'oral.

Comment: Le deuxième est correcte ?

Comment: D'accord avec @SimonDéchamps, on ne peut pas dans cette construction séparer l'attribut du verbe, il faut le mettre avant le sujet.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps, exact et merci, il faut éviter de séparer pour la deuxième (ou rapprocher l'adjectif), j'ai corrigé ma réponse.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Tu as corrigé mais en disant qu'elle n'est 'pas très correcte', mais 'souvent utilisée', et 'plus lourde'. Alors qu'elle est totalement incorrecte, absolument jamais utilisée, et pas simplement lourde mais carrément fausse. Si j'entends quelqu'un dire ça, c'est que c'est un anglophone qui essaie de parler français en utilisant la même structure qu'en anglais.