# Inversions in questions

Tags: grammaire, questions, interrogative

I had a French test the other day and one of the questions was this one:

> Transformez les questions informelles en questions formelles en
>   utilisant l’inversion, comme dans l’exemple : Vous allez au cinéma ce
>   soir ? --> Allez-vous au cinéma ce soir ?
>
> 1. Elle habite où ? ____________________________
> 2. Qu’est-ce qu’ils feront après le concert ? _________________________________
> 3. Marc va à Lille quand ? _______________________

I managed to get the first two examples right:

1. Où habite-t-elle?
2. Que feront-ils après le concert?

but for the third one I wrote *Quand va Marc à Lille ?* which was incorrect. My teacher told me it should be *Quand Marc va-t-il à Lille ?*

I've never heard of this before, do people really use that form or is it just prescribed in grammars?

Comment: Yes, that form is correct. It's a little classy, but if you're using inversion, you have to do something like that. Here's a thread with the same question and a couple of answers: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24563/pourquoi-lhôtel-est-il-complet-why-est-il-and-not-just-est

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quand Marc va-t-il à Lille?

is the answer. It's said and heard, but maybe declining in usage. It sounds a bit too "correct". We might lower the language level in conversation by saying:

> Quand est-ce que Marc va à Lille?

Comment: Too bad; the internal rhyme and rhythm of "va-t-il à Lille" is so nice. :p

Comment: Hey - you can absolutely use it :-) Sometimes also with kids, we intentionally use the over-correct form to teach them proper French. And sometimes we use "over-correct" forms just because we like speaking "correctly" :-)

Comment: I'd add that one of the reasons for which "Quand Marc va-t-il à Lille?" sounds slightly weird is that in formal usage we wouldn't use the present tense to talk about the future. "Quand ira-t-il à Lille?" or "Quand ira Marc  à Lille?" is how I would hear it in formal talk, with "Quand Marc va-t-il à Lille?" being a kind of hybrid of formal and common usage.

Comment: *Quand est-ce que Marc va à Lille ?* still sounds written French to me. More usual Spoken French forms would be *Il va quand à Lille, Marc ?*, *Quand est-ce qu'il va à Lille, Marc ?*, or *Quand c'est qu'il va à Lille, Marc ?*

Comment: Et encore: _Quand c'est qu'il y va, à Lille, Marc?_, _C'est quand qu'il va à Lille, Marc?_, _C'est quand qu'y va à Lille, le Marc?_ ... on n'arrête pas le progrès ;-)

Comment: @Frank Pourquoi *le Marc* ? Et puis, est-ce qu'on peut aussi dire *Marc, quand va-t-il à Lille ?*

Comment: Merci à toutes et à tous!

Comment: Oui, on peut dire _Marc, quand va-t-il à Lille?_, ou peut-être pas. Un peu bizarre, et ce _Marc_ en tête de phrase ne semble pas bien situé. Pourquoi _le Marc_? Ha! :-) c'est une tournure très familière et campagnarde, dans certaines régions. Ce n'est pas considéré "correct". Encore une, pour la route: _c'est quand qu'y vas-t'y à Lille, le Marc?_. J'ai entendu une de mes grand-mères parler comme ça dans le Limousin, il y a longtemps.

Comment: @Frank Pourquoi est-ce que Marc en tête de phrase ne semble pas bien situé ? A cause de l'interrogatif ? Si je dis: *Marc, il est parti  à Lille* c'est toujours bizzare ou pas ? Merci pour les informations, je trouve le registre familier très intéressant. :) Désolé pour les fautes de grammaire. :(

Comment: Si c'est une phrase affirmative, _Marc, il est parti à Lille._, ce n'est pas parfaitement correct (à cause de la répétition du sujet), mais ça se dit tous les jours, avec une nuance d'insistance sur _Marc_: être en tête de phrase confère plus d'importance à ce mot. Si c'est une phrase interrogative, on pourrait dire _Marc? Il est parti à Lille?_ pour montrer sa surprise que Marc soit parti. Mais _Marc, quand va-t-il à Lille?_, à mon avis, ne se dit pas. _Marc? Quand va-t-il à Lille?_ est possible.

Comment: @Frank D'accord, j'ai compris. Merci mille fois!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, people use it. And yes, it is formal** , but not more formal than the two others examples. The test was about transforming the informal questions into formal ones, and in that case it is completely correct. The three examples are definitely something you would write (and read), less likely something you would say - except in particularly classy circumstances.

The amazing part is, the first question is actually the exact same and you got it right! Basically, it is the "inversion rule" (verb then pronoun), with an extra "-t-" to link the two words (which you have from the silent t in "feront-ils").

Comment: The answer to number 3 is not the same as the answer to number 1, since in no. 1 he did not need to add a pronoun. Had no. 3 read "Il va à Lille quand ?" the OP probably would have answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence sounds like something that **will happen**, so in my opinion the most correct and precise translation in french would be (using future):

> Quand Marc ira t-il à Lille ?

It is not an exact translation, as it change the time used in the sentence, but it is more litteral.

Comment: It depends on the context. For example, if the answer is "Tous les dimanches." (Every Sunday), then "Quand Marc va-t-il à Lille ?" is more appropriate.